# Cómo pasar una propiedad que se obtiene desde un componente hijo a un componente padre React.js

Tags: reactjs

estoy aprendiendo React y estoy desarrollando una integración a la api OMDB para buscar y obtener películas, el detalle es que tengo un componente Respuesta que recibe la búsqueda de la query, con un botón, lo que deseo hacer, es tomar el valor del item que estoy trabajando y guardarlo state.idBusqueda.

El dato que deseo guardar en el state, lo estoy obteniendo desde el componente hijo directamente, agradecería su ayuda

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      busquedaActiva: false,
      busqueda: '',
      resultadoQuery: [],
      modalVisible: false,
      idBusqueda: '',
      infoModal: {}
    };

    this.apiUrl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?';

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.realizarBusqueda = this.realizarBusqueda.bind(this);
    this.modalVisible = this.modalVisible.bind(this);
    this.mostrarModal = this.mostrarModal.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      busqueda: event.target.value
    });
  }

  async realizarBusqueda() {
    let queryBusqueda = this.state.busqueda.split(" ").join("+").toLocaleLowerCase();
    let queryTotal = this.apiUrl+"s="+queryBusqueda+"&type=movie&apikey=21f8f6b3";
    let response = await axios.get(`${queryTotal}`);
    this.setState({
      resultadoQuery: response.data,
    });
  }

  modalVisible(idPelicula) {
    console.log(idPelicula);
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: true,
      idBusqueda: idPelicula
    });
  }

  mostrarModal() {
    console.log("ejecutando el modal");
    if (this.state.modalVisible) {
      return <div>{this.state.idBusqueda}</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>El modal no es visible</div>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Buscador handleChange={this.handleChange} realizarBusqueda={this.realizarBusqueda}/>
        <Respuesta resultadoQuery={this.state.resultadoQuery} busquedaActiva={this.state.busquedaActiva} busqueda={this.state.busqueda} modalVisible={ () => {this.modalVisible()}}/>
        {
          this.state.modalVisible &&
            <Modal idBusqueda={this.state.idBusqueda}/>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Buscador = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={props.handleChange}/>
    <button onClick={props.realizarBusqueda}>Buscar</button>
    </div>
  );
}


const Respuesta = (props) => {
  if (props.resultadoQuery.Search) {
    return(
      <div>
        {props.resultadoQuery.Search.map((item, index) => {
          return (<div key={index}>
            <p>{item.Title}</p>
            <button onClick={() => {props.modalVisible()}}>Ver pelicula</button>
          </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
  else if (props.busqueda.length>0) {
    return(
      <p>Falló la búsqueda</p>
    );
  } else {
    return(
      <p>No hay búsqueda</p>
    );
  }
}

const Modal = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>{props.idBusqueda}</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Componente Respuesta => Aloja todos los resultados del componente búsqueda.

idBusqueda => es el estado al que quiero llegar y poder modificar de forma correcta

modalVisible => es el método que desearía utilizar para hacer la modificación del estado idBusqueda.

Comment: Osea quieres que cuando en el componente Respuesta le de click al boton llame a un metodo del padre y que guarde algun dato? Como el titulo o el id por ejempl? No lo entendi muy bien la verdad